# Value for SMD crystal marking: 33b00JZ, needed

Tags: components, surface-mount, crystal

Does anyone know the value (frequency) of an SMD crystal with marking 33b00JZ? Datasheet link will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the marking might be 33600 not 33b00

Comment: The image is rather blurry (can you try to get a sharper one?) but I agree with RedGrittyBrick; it looks like that could be a 6.

Comment: Which device that is?

Comment: The marking is definitely 33b00jz. I have the same crystal on a similar pcb but with marking: 33b00je.

Answer (score 1):

From the markings, mostly, it's probably 33.00MHz. You could check the surrounding chips to see if there is a recommended frequency, but that may not help in this case.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Is there a 33.00MHz crystal? I come across 32.768MHz mostly.

Comment: Yes, that's a plausible number for crystals in that case. According to distribution, more popular than 32.678MHz. Of course 32.768kHz is extremely popular, but rarely, if ever, in the HC-49S/ HC-49/US package.